# Will PnP Provisioning migrate workflows including with forms(infopath)

Tags: pnp-powershell, pnp-provision

Can the PnP provisioning migrate infopath forms with workflows(SharePoint Designer) with ease?
As anyone use this template successfully before ?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Workflows are working. See [The docs](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Provisioning-Schema/blob/master/ProvisioningSchema-2019-03.md#workflows) for reference.

InfoPath-forms are not supported by PnP and most probably never will be. Check out Vesa Juvonens comment on [this issue](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/issues/530).

Comment: THanks Nils for the reply